# Adding length limit when deserializing a String, a Vec or an Array

Tags: security, rust, deserialization, serde

## How does one add a limit over length of a `String` (`Vec` or `Array`) when deserializing using `serde` ?

Best guess is:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use arrayvec::ArrayString;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    #[serde(try_from = "ArrayString<4096>")] // FAILS!
    bar: String,
}
```

Which does not work because `try_from` attribute is only available for "containers" and not "fields".

If there is a way to make this solution work, the main concerns are **efficiency** and **security**. Is this solution fast (not dramatically slowing down the deserialization process for short `String`) and safe (does it prevents the memory from being used up by a malicious request), and is it idiomatic ?

Comment: Generally I think you should limit the size of a given request at the router layer, not at deserialization.

Comment: In fact I don't think this is possible given the architecture of serde.

Comment: Well, I already do that. And if I want, I can reject deserialized type that do not fit a predicat but I'd find nicer to have exceeding size limit error part of the deserialization. In other words, make invalid state unrepresentable.

Comment: By the point the `Deserialize` implementation sees the string the `Deserializer` will already have read the whole of it, thus you don't gain efficiency nor security by restricting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @cafce25, by the point your `Deserialize` impl gets the string, it is already fully parsed from the input stream. This is just how `serde` works, and thus this restriction will not provide any protection.

You **must** implement this kind of restriction at the request level, or with your own parser.

If you still wish to implement a restriction like this, it's pretty simple to do with a newtype that delegates to `String::deserialize`:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use serde::de;
use serde::Deserialize;

struct LimitedString<const MAX_LENGTH: usize>(String);

impl<const MAX_LENGTH: usize> Deref for LimitedString<MAX_LENGTH> {
    type Target = String;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<'de, const MAX_LENGTH: usize> de::Deserialize<'de> for LimitedString<MAX_LENGTH> {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: de::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        <String as de::Deserialize>::deserialize(deserializer).and_then(|inner| {
            if inner.len() > MAX_LENGTH {
                Err(de::Error::invalid_length(inner.len(), &"an integer lower than the maximum"))
            } else {
                Ok(Self(inner))
            }
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo {
    bar: LimitedString<4096>,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd46db0820087a811d5d5658d978f5e9)